# How to remove rechargable LED SI Urban integrated light strip from cannondale bad boy

Tags: cannondale, led-lights

I have the Cannondale Bad Boy and the LED lights are almost dead, I need to recharge it but can't figure out how to remove the lights from the handlebars to charge them. 
Here are the type of lights on this bike: https://www.cannondaleexperts.com/Cannondale-Urban-Si-Integrated-LED-Light_p_2311.html

I undid the 2 screws and seems like it should just pull out but i can't get it, don't want to break the casing or have to take the handlebars apart, anybody know a trick to getting it out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So that is exactly what it looked like once removed. However it was fit in there too tight to be pulled out from the front. I ended up taking it to the LBS and they took apart the headset partially and pushed it out from the back for me. Luckily the battery does last a couple months with almost daily usage of about 30 mins. So I'll probably just have to get comfortable with taking the headset apart myself or just slide it back in with some grease and a string tied to the back of it.

Comment: You're probably best to file or sand whatever part of the plastic case is binding.  Disassembling the headset/stem would be bad for it over time even if its only 6 times a year because its not intended to come apart frequently.

Comment: Another option might be a simple pull-tongue made of duct tape sticking out below between the light and the frame.  Could look okay or ugly depending on your viewpoint.

Comment: Lastly if its just minor sticking, some slight layer of lithium grease might be all it needs to get out easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own one, but by this photo it should pull straight out the front after undoing the two screws.

[image]

One would hope the battery has decent life - screwing things into and out of the bars frequently would be really annoying.

Comment: Is that a USB mini port in the pic? I would try charging it by using the port.

Comment: @P.Barney yes - OP's question was about how to get the light out of the frame of the bike, in order to charge it.  Based oin that photo, the light has to pull out the front which will expose the USB port.